# Passing Data Between PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, jquery

What I am trying to do is generate a series of buttons with PHP which correspond to names in a MySQL database. When the user selects the button it will display different text in an overlay popup depending on the button selected. I'm fairly new to PHP, jQuery, etc. so for now I am trying to get something a little simpler to work (without the database part). Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/theme.css">
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

echo "<form name=\"idpass\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<div>";
echo "<button name=\"button\" id=\"button1\" value=\"One\" class=\"One_open\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\">User 1</button>";
echo "<button name=\"button\" id=\"button2\" value=\"Two\" class=\"Two_open\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\">User 2</button>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>";

if(!isset($_POST["button"]))
{
    echo "click something";
}

else
{
    $buttonSelection = $_POST["button"];
    echo "<div id=\"" . $buttonSelection ."\">";
    echo "Hello, " . $buttonSelection;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>

<script>

$(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
{
    var me = $(this);
    $('#'+me.val()).popup();
}); 
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This will generate two buttons named User 1 and User 2. The problem is if I click them slowly, the text ("Hello, One" or "Hello, Two") simply appears below the buttons on the page, not in the popup. If I click them fast enough however, it works. So I know the data is getting passed but there is obviously a delay and I'm not sure where?

EDIT: Here is the code for the popup (it was not developed by me):

```js
 /**
 * jQuery Popup Overlay
 *
 * @version 1.4.0
 * @requires jQuery v1.7.1+
 * @link http://vast-eng.github.com/jquery-popup-overlay/
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 */

;(function($) {

var level = [];
var lastclicked = [];

$.fn.popup = $.fn.popup = function(customoptions) {

    var $body = $('body'),
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        $el,
        $newel,
        $wrapper,
        options = {},
        blurhandler,
        focushandler,
        defaults = {
            type: 'overlay',
            action: 'click',
            background: true,
            color: 'black',
            opacity: '0.4',
            horizontal: 'center',
            vertical: 'center',
            escape: false,
            blur: true,
            fade: 250,
            opensufix: '_open',
            closesufix: '_close',
            keepfocus: true,
            reposition: false,
            autozindex: false,
        };

    var init = function(el) {

            if(!$(el).attr('id')){
                $(el).attr('id', 'j-popup-' + parseInt(Math.random() * 100000000));
            }

            lastclicked[el.id] = false;
            level[el.id] = 0;
            $el = $(el);
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, customoptions);

            /**
             * Repositioningtion parameter
             */
            if (options.reposition === true) {
                // @TODO - not so DRY...
                $newel = $el;
                $el = $wrapper = $('#' + el.id + '_wrapper');
                positionpopup(el);
                return false;
            }

            // initialize on only once
            if ($el.attr('data-popup-initialized')) {
                return false;
            }
            $el.attr('data-popup-initialized', 'true');

            /**
             * Set variables
             */
            var triggerelement = '.' + el.id + options.opensufix; // class that will open popup


            /**
             * Set other options that are related for type: tooltip
             */
            if (options.type == 'tooltip') {
                options.background = false;
                options.keepfocus = false;
            }

            /**
             * Hide popups that aren't already hidden with CSS and move it to the top or bottom of the <body> tag
             */
            $el.css({
                display: 'none'
            });
            // append instead of prepend if document is ready
            // if (((document.readyState === 'interactive') || (document.readyState === 'complete')) && !($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 8)) {
            //  $body.append(el);
            // } else {
            $body.prepend(el);
            // }

            /**
             * Create background div and append to the top or bottom of the body tag
             */
            if ((options.background) && (!$('#' + el.id + '_background').length)) {

                // Append instead of prepend if possible
                var popupback = '<div id="' + el.id + '_background" class="popup_background"></div>';
                // if (((document.readyState === 'interactive') || (document.readyState === 'complete')) && !($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 8)) {
                //  $body.append(popupback);
                // } else {
                $body.prepend(popupback);
                // }

                $('#' + el.id + '_background').css({
                    backgroundColor: options.color,
                    opacity: options.opacity,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0',
                    right: '0',
                    bottom: '0',
                    left: '0',
                    display: 'none'
                });

            }

            /**
             * Positioning overlay
             */
            if (options.type == 'overlay') {

                $el.css({
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    textAlign: 'left',
                    position: 'relative',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle'
                }).addClass('popup_content');

                $el.wrap('<div id="' + el.id + '_wrapper" class="popup_wrapper" />');
                $wrapper = $('#' + el.id + '_wrapper');
                $wrapper.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0',
                    left: '0',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    display: 'none',
                    textAlign: 'center'
                });

                $wrapper.append('<div class="popup_align" />');
                $('.popup_align').css({
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    height: '100%'
                });

                // overlay horizontal
                if (options.horizontal == 'right') {
                    $wrapper.css('text-align', 'right');
                } else if (options.horizontal == 'left') {
                    $wrapper.css('text-align', 'left');
                }

                // overlay vertical
                if (options.vertical == 'bottom') {
                    $el.css('vertical-align', 'bottom');
                } else if (options.vertical == 'top') {
                    $el.css('vertical-align', 'top');
                }

                $newel = $el;
                $el = $wrapper;
            }

            /**
             * add data-popup-order attribute
             */
            $(triggerelement).each(function(i, item) {
                $(item).attr('data-popup-order', i);
            });

            /**
             * Defining on which event to open/close popup
             */
            if (options.action == 'click') {
                // open
                $(triggerelement).click(function(e) {
                    if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
                        var or = $(this).attr('data-popup-order');
                        dopopup(el, or);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
                //
                $('.' + el.id + options.closesufix).click(function(e) {
                    hidePopUp(el);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            } else if (options.action == 'hover') {
                $(triggerelement).mouseenter(

                function() {
                    dopopup(el, $(this).attr('data-popup-order'));
                });
                $(triggerelement).mouseleave(

                function() {
                    hidePopUp(el);
                });
            } else {
                $(triggerelement).mouseover(

                function() {
                    dopopup(el, $(this).attr('data-popup-order'));
                });
                $(triggerelement).mouseout(

                function() {
                    hidePopUp(el);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Close popup on ESC key (binded only if a popup is open)
             */
            if (options.escape) {
                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 27 && $el.css('display') == 'block') {
                        hidePopUp(el);
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * Repositioning popup when window resize
             */
            $(window).bind('resize', function() {
                if (options.type != 'tooltip') {
                    positionpopup(el);
                }
            });


            /**
             * Z-index calculation
             */
            if (options.autozindex === true) {
                var maxZIndex = Math.max(0, Math.max.apply(null, $.map($.makeArray(document.getElementsByTagName("*")), function(v) {
                    return parseFloat($(v).css("z-index")) || null;
                })));
                level[el.id] = maxZIndex;

                // add z-index to the wrapper
                if (level[el.id] > 0) {
                    $el.css({
                        zIndex: (level[el.id] + 2)
                    });
                }

                // add z-index to the background
                if (options.background) {
                    if (level[el.id] > 0) {
                        $('#' + el.id + '_background').css({
                            zIndex: (level[el.id] + 1)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Automaticaly open popup on start, if autoopen option is set
             */
            if (options.autoopen) {
                dopopup(el, 0);
            }

        }; // init
    /**
     * Popup method
     *
     * @param el - popup element
     * @param order - element which triggered this method
     */
    var dopopup = function(el, order) {

            var clickplace = order;

            /**
             * beforeopen Callback
             */
            callback(options.beforeopen, clickplace);

            // remember last clicked place
            lastclicked[el.id] = clickplace;

            // show popup
            if (options.fade) {
                $el.fadeIn(options.fade, function() {
                    $(document).on('click', blurhandler);
                    $(document).on('focusin', focushandler);
                });
            } else {
                $el.show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(document).on('click', blurhandler);
                    $(document).on('focusin', focushandler);
                }, 0);
            }

            // position
            positionpopup(el, clickplace);


            // show background
            if (options.background) {
                if (options.fade) {
                    $('#' + el.id + '_background').fadeIn(options.fade);
                } else {
                    $('#' + el.id + '_background').show();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Keep focus inside dialog box
             */
            if (options.keepfocus) {

                // make overlay holder div focusable and focus it
                $newel.attr('tabindex', -1).focus();

                focushandler = function(e) {
                    if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is('#' + el.id)) {
                        $newel.focus();
                    }
                };

            }

            /**
             * onOpen Callback
             */
            callback(options.onOpen, clickplace);

            /**
             * Close popup on blur
             */
            if (options.blur) {
                blurhandler = function(e) {
                    if (!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().is('#' + el.id)) {
                        hidePopUp(el);
                    }
                };
            }

        };

    /**
     * Position popup
     *
     * @param el
     */
    var positionpopup = function(el, clickplace) {
            clickplace = clickplace || 0;

            // TOOLTIP
            if (options.type == 'tooltip') {
                $el.css({
                    'position': 'absolute'
                });
                var $link = $('.' + el.id + options.opensufix + '[data-popup-order="' + clickplace + '"]');
                var linkOffset = $link.offset();

                // tooltip horizontal
                if (options.horizontal == 'right') {
                    $el.css('left', linkOffset.left + $link.outerWidth());
                } else if (options.horizontal == 'left') {
                    $el.css('right', $(window).width() - linkOffset.left);
                } else {
                    $el.css('left', linkOffset.left + ($link.outerWidth() / 2) - ($(el).outerWidth() / 2) - parseFloat($(el).css('marginLeft')) );
                }

                // tooltip vertical
                if (options.vertical == 'bottom') {
                    $el.css('top', linkOffset.top + $link.outerHeight());
                } else if (options.vertical == 'top') {
                    $el.css('bottom', $(window).height() - linkOffset.top);
                } else {
                    $el.css('top', linkOffset.top + ($link.outerHeight() / 2) - ($(el).outerHeight() / 2) - parseFloat($(el).css('marginTop')) );
                }

            // OVERLAY
            } else if (options.type == 'overlay') {
                // if height of the popup exceeds the visible area – make the popup scrollable
                if ($window.height() < ($newel.outerHeight() + parseFloat($newel.css('marginTop')) + parseFloat($newel.css('marginBottom')))) {
                    $el.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: $window.scrollTop()
                    });
                } else {
                    $el.css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: '0'
                    });
                }
            }

        };

    /**
     * Hide popup
     *
     * @param {DOM Object} el
     */
    var hidePopUp = function(el) {

            // hide background
            if (options.background) {
                if (options.fade) {
                    $('#' + el.id + '_background').fadeOut(options.fade);
                } else {
                    $('#' + el.id + '_background').hide();
                }
            }

            // unbind event for blur when popup closes
            if (options.blur) {
                $(document).off('click', blurhandler);
            }

            if (options.keepfocus) {
                $(document).off('focusin', focushandler);
                // focus opening link on popup close
                $('.' + el.id + options.opensufix).focus();
            }

            // hide popup
            if (options.fade) {
                $el.fadeOut(options.fade);
            } else {
                $el.hide();
            }

            /**
             * onClose callback
             */
            callback(options.onClose, lastclicked[el.id]);
        };

    /**
     * Callbacks calls
     *
     * @param func - callback function
     * @param clickplace
     */
    var callback = function(func, clickplace) {
            var cp = $('.' + $el.attr('id') + options.opensufix + '[data-popup-order="' + clickplace + '"]');
            if (typeof func == 'function') {
                func(cp);
            }
        };

    this.each(function() {
        init(this);
    });

};  //fn.popup

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What popup? You did'nt include any javascript, just a php file that outputs the buttons value below the HTML!

Comment: We need to see your JS code.

Comment: Careful, you've got an XSS vulnerability there.  Always make sure to wrap any variable data with `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting it into HTML.  If you are using variable data in JavaScript, use `json_encode()` instead.

Comment: @Brad, thank you I will make the change.

Comment: @DerekHenderson the code snippets are scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used this before, but I see that the plugin is modifying the divs and creating new ones as wrappers, etc.  If you are modifying / generating the div on the fly then perhaps there is a race condition. Also i don't see where you are setting any options on `popup()` -- it seems that you want `{autoopen : true}`

Anyway, no race condition in this fiddle as I'm dynamically updating the contents of one single div that persists and used as the modal so it seems to work fine.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/MTM89/)

```
$('#modal').popup({autoopen : true});
```

The plugin seems to have a bug where it can only be instantiated so I added it to a cloned element and destroy it when hidden.  If it has a reopen method then use that bug I could not see it.

```
$(function () {
    var destroyModal = function(){
        $(this).remove();
   }
    $("button").click(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        $('.modal').clone().text( me.val() )
       .popup({autoopen : true, onclose : destroyModal});   
        return false;
    }); // end click
}); // end ready
```